# Reset object rotation back to 0 degrees

Tags: inkscape

When I rotate a text or other object in InkScape manually (by clicking on it twice, slowly) I can't seem to be able to rotate it back to 0 degrees *exactly*.

When I access Transformation menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>), there is just relative rotation option. But the absolute rotation **must be known**, when the text is rotated!

So where do I edit absolute object rotation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not aware of any elegant solution, but it can be done with the XML Editor.

1. Select the rotated object.
2. Click the *XML Editor* button on the toolbar.

   [image: XML Editor button]
3. Selected element will also be selected in the XML Editor. Find the *transform* property on the right and click it.

   [image: XML Editor with element's transform property selected]
4. Change the value to `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)` and click *Set*.

This will reset all transformations applied to the selected object.

Comment: Thank you. Using XML editor is just fine for me. Can I somehow write a macro that does this instantly?

Comment: I have never used macros so I can't really tell you if it's possible.

Comment: Tip for Googlers: No need to type `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)`: just clear the stuff in the value box out and press set to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting it to the identity matrix, simply delete the "transform" attribute by clicking to the red "x" icon above the attribute view.

Comment: Where can I find the attribute view?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tip: paths need to be "grouped" before you try to rotate, or there is no transform property applied.  Rotating a path without grouping it simply changes the coordinates of all the path's points.

So in order to see the "transform" property in the XML editor, select the path and hit CTRL-G before rotating.  Then any rotations will be applied to the *group*, not the individual path, thus creating the "transform" property in the XML editor.

Hope this helps!